# How to parse the ejabberd JID into its parts

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

Im writing and ejabberd module that checks if the user exists to do something, im using ejabberd_auth_external:is_user_exists("USER", "HOST") to achieve that however i don't have the USER but the full JID in the form of USER@HOST/RESOURCE, is there any way to get the USER out of that string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function string:tokens/2 with separator "@" and the first element of returned list will be user name:

```
JID = "user.name@host/resource".
[User|_] = string:tokens(JID, "@").
```

Answer (score 4):

The typical way in ejabberd to do this is using `jlib:string_to_jid/1` function:

```
-include("jlib.hrl").
...
case jlib:string_to_jid(String) of
    #jid{luser = LUser, lserver = LServer} ->
        ejabberd_auth:is_user_exists(LUser, LServer);
    error ->
        false
end.
```

Also, don't use functions from `ejabberd_auth_external` module directly. Use `ejabberd_auth` instead.

Comment: Edit: in recent ejabberd versions you should use jid:from_string/1 instead in order to avoid compile warnings.